# How to remove tooltip in ant-design donut chart

Tags: reactjs, charts, components, antd, donut-chart

I am trying to remove the tooltip from the donut chart in @ant-design/plots.

I have tried passing `tooltip:false` to the label object which didn't work.

```
const config = {
    appendPadding: 10,
    data,
    angleField: 'value',
    colorField: 'type',
    radius: 1,
    innerRadius: 0.6,
    label: {
    tooltip:false,
      type: 'inner',
      offset: '-50%',
      content: '{value}',
      style: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontSize: 14,
      },
    },
    interactions: [
      {
        type: 'element-selected',
      },
      {
        type: 'element-active',
      },
    ],
    statistic: {
      title: false,
      content: {
        style: {
          whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap',
          overflow: 'hidden',
          textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
        },
        content: 'AntV\nG2Plot',
      },
    },
  };
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

### tooltip:false should be in config object

tooltip is a property under Plot Components in the [API](https://charts.ant.design/en/examples/pie/donut#basic)

To remove the tooltip you should pass it directly in the config object.

```
const config = {
    tooltip:false,
    appendPadding: 10,
    data,
    angleField: 'value',
    colorField: 'type',
    radius: 1,
    innerRadius: 0.6,
    label: {
      type: 'inner',
      offset: '-50%',
      content: '{value}',
      style: {
        textAlign: 'center',
        fontSize: 14,
      },
    },
    interactions: [
      {
        type: 'element-selected',
      },
      {
        type: 'element-active',
      },
    ],
    statistic: {
      title: false,
      content: {
        style: {
          whiteSpace: 'pre-wrap',
          overflow: 'hidden',
          textOverflow: 'ellipsis',
        },
        content: 'AntV\nG2Plot',
      },
    },
  };
```